# How do I tie a audio track volume slider to the physical volume buttons

Tags: iphone, volume

I would like to tie the slider action of the volume control to the volume buttons so if the buttons are used the slider adjusts as well. I thought this was possible but I am not sure.

Currently I have a working slider volume control but it is not tied to the physical buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested these, just did a bit of research and copied and pasted.

1a. get the volume from the device.

```
    float volume = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume];
    self.volume = vol;
```

or

```
    #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
    //...
    float vol = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer].volume;
    self.volume = vol;
```

1b. get notified when volume changes

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
       addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
       name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
       object:nil];

  -(void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification*)notification{
    float vol = [[[notification userInfo] 
                 objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"] 
                 floatValue];
    self.volume = vol;
   }
  // Some said the Notification used is a private apple API so you should do a bit of research for using it in a app you are submitting to apple.
  // There is also this notification though: MPMusicPlayerControllerVolumeDidChangeNotification
```

2. Set the slider to the volume.

   ```
   self.volumeSlider.value = (double) self.volume;
   ```

Or 
Use MPVolumeView from apple

> Use a volume view to present the user with a slider control for setting the system audio output volume, and a button for choosing the audio output route. When first displayed, the slider’s position reflects the current system audio output volume. As the user drags the slider, the changes update the volume. If the user presses the device volume buttons while sound is playing, the slider moves to reflect the new volume.
>      - [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/)

```
     mpVolumeViewParentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     MPVolumeView *myVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: mpVolumeViewParentView.bounds];
     [mpVolumeViewParentView addSubview: myVolumeView];
```

**Edit:**
From reading the MPMediaPlayer docs it does seem as if Apple wants everyone to use their own volume slider and customise the look of it if needed.

Comment: This is a very detailed and useful answer. Good Job!